# facebook FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange') not working

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

For the life of me I cant get Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange') to work. See code below

```
  <div id="fb-root">
    </div>
    <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({
                appId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', // App ID
                channelUrl: 'http://XXXXXXXX.us/', // Channel File
                status: true, // check login status
                cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
            });

            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {
                alert('The status of the session is: ' + response.status);
            });
        };


        // Load the SDK Asynchronously
        (function (d) {
            var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
            js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
        } (document));
    </script>
    <div class="fb-login-button" data-size="xlarge" scope="email" data-show-faces="false"
        data-width="400" data-max-rows="1" autologoutlink="true">
        Login with Facebook</div>
```

The login button renders. and i can logout too. only problem is that the auth.response change is not firing and i am not getting the "message" popup

Comment: FBML will be deprecated soon. Better not use it.

Comment: @InspiredJW FBML is already deprecated, this is XFBML, something which is not going to be deprecated.

Comment: have you tried checking just `response[0]`? according to the documentation, *Note that for some cases, the value of response is unkeyed, but when more than one variable is returned, it contains the appropriate keys.* => http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

Answer (score -1):

Your code looks fine.

I would access your Facebook app and check on 2 settings in particular.

1. Check 'Sandbox Mode' -ensure it's set to 'Disabled'
2. Check your Site URL and/or Canvas URL -ensure they are set to your domain. (i.e. if you are working on this locally your url should look something like `http://localhost:#####/` where ##### is your port.

Hope that helps.

Comment: hey, do you know how to find out my port number for this?

Comment: If you're working in Visual Studio, from your Solution Explorer right click on your web project and click Properties. On your left, 3rd down, choose Web. In the Servers section select 'Specific port' and either use the default or choose a new one.

Answer (score -4):

Your fbAsyncInit function is called asynchronously so you won't see any alert messages. Try console.log instead for debugging.